# How to load toolbox items of different domain specific languages

Tags: c#, dsl

I have 'n' different domain specifc languages e.g. language1, language2, ...., languagen each of which contains different toolbox items. Let say first language is for banking process, second one is for health process, third one is for insurance process etc.

I want to load toolbox items of every above mentioned languages into every language. i.e. the toolbox item defined in banking process should be visible and functional in all other languages i.e. inside health and insurance languages resp.

Answer (score 0):

You might try asking the DSL forum on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dslvsarchx/threads